# Angular6 : ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have created an angular 6 app for generating the reactive form dynamically from a json object. But for the radio type ONLY it showing some error like

**ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.**

[stackblitz LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typeinformationdynamic)

Did I miss any attribute/key in the html template??

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol

Comment: Try including `MatInputModule`

Comment: @akash already included !!

Comment: is your problem resolved.?

Answer (score 0):

This error will happen if you forget to put the material tag (such as matInput) for the input inside the mat-form-field.