# Angular / Mat Table - How to create a custom table component wrapping mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to create my own table component to add a checkbox column and actions around a set of ng-container for columns.

Example

```
<my-table>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="someCol">...</ng-container>
</my-table>
```

The custom table component would have

```
<table matTable>
Columns local to component 
+ columns passed from the component
</table>
```

Unfortunately (and obviously) I lose all the context and variables. I just don't know how to get about it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you trying to wrap `mat-table` so you won't have to do all the plumbings every time you pass an array of objects to it ?

Comment: It's a fun idea. Where is your code???

Comment: The goal is to have a fixed set of columns (checkbox) in that custom table and then just add to it in a flexible fashion.

Comment: @SoEzPz I don't have code yet. I tried things with <ng-content> but it breaks so I gave up and thought I'd ask first.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335929/content-projection-inside-angular-material-table.