# mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl and already imported

Tags: angular, angular-material

I get the error `ERROR mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl` which should mean that I need to import MatFormFieldModule in my nearest parent module. But I already did, so I don't understand what the problem is...

**template**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <textarea
            matInput
            placeholder="Active Description"
            formControlName="activeDescription"
        ></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <textarea
            matInput
            placeholder="Inactive Description"
            formControlName="inactiveDescription"
        ></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="active">Active</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**module**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { PaymentConfigSelectorComponent } from './payment-config-selector/payment-config-selector.component';
import { PaymentMethodComponent } from './payment-method/payment-method.component';
import { PaymentMethodsComponent } from './payment-methods/payment-methods.component';
import { PaymentRoutingModule } from './payment-routing.module';
import { PaymentEffects } from './payment.effects';
import { paymentReducer } from './payment.reducer';
import { PaymentSmartComponent } from './smart/payment-smart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PaymentSmartComponent, PaymentMethodsComponent, PaymentConfigSelectorComponent, PaymentMethodComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PaymentRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([PaymentEffects]),
    StoreModule.forFeature(
      'payment',
      paymentReducer,
    ),
    MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
})
export class PaymentModule { }
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Actually the error doesn't mean a module import problem, but that you're using the `mat-form-field` without a valid control.

The problem is here :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="active">Active</mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

MatChebox isn't intended to be contained in a `mat-form-field` but yeah its name is not very clear ... Keep just in mind that `mat-form-field` is the component that handles underline + hint + floating label + errors, etc ...

The list of supported child component is : input / textarea / select / chip-list (see https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Comment: Thank you, thats correct. But it doesn't make any sense I think, since it IS indeed a form "field" - or at least part of the form. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: yep that's badly named. It's more like a `mat-form-text-field` because it's the component that add an underlined + hint + floating label + errors ... etc

Comment: Is there an alternative to mat-form-field to be used by mat-checkbox? because all my form fields use mat-form-field, except a checkbox, and so this one is not aligned with other fields.

Answer (score 16):

I had to do this to get it to work:-

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input hidden=true matInput> // this gets rid of the error, while the form still uses the input received in the
  mat-checkbox
  <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="active">Active</mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 12):

I fixed the issue by adding a hidden input field.

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>My Label</mat-label>
 <input matInput [hidden]="true" [(ngModel)]="myModel" name="myModel">
 <mat-checkbox class="ml-3" [(ngModel)]="myModel" name="myModel"></mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a 'div' with class 'mat-form-field' did the trick for me :

```
<div class="mat-form-field">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="didAcceptTerms">
        <span
        [innerHTML]="'booking.submit.didAcceptTerms.lbl'|translate"></span>
    </mat-checkbox>
    <mat-error *ngIf="f.didAcceptTerms.errors">
        {{ 'booking.submit.didAcceptTerms.error' | translate }}
    </mat-error>    
</div>
```

Comment: This works better IMO because of the way the mat-form-field adds design elements.  It would be nice if they updated it to work with mat-checkbox though.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was using a Material but needed to add
`import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';`

to my module and then add 
`MatInputModule` 
to my `imports` array.

Make sure you have everything imported in your parent module that is necessary for use.

Comment: This may not be the most common source of the problem but it exactly what I was doing wrong.  Thanks.