# ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl while using API documentation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-8

I imported the `MatFormFieldModule` like this:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    //import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
    import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
    //    MaterialModule,
        MatFormFieldModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Within `app.component.html` I have (Taken straight from the API documentation):

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Input">
    </mat-form-field>

ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

Any ideas?

And I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

Comment: Is this somewhat related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `MatInputModule` as well:

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ...
  ]
})
```

otherwise Angular doesn't know how to initialize directive for `<input matInput` which provides `MatFormFieldControl`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: `input[matInput], textarea[matInput], select[matNativeControl],
      input[matNativeControl], textarea[matNativeControl]`,
  ...
  providers: [{provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: MatInput}],
})
```