# angular => issue with form with material table inside

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups, angular-material-table

In angular 7, I am trying to develop a page where i will be showing data in table format , and also want to give user access to edit, add and delete. I am facing problem in adding formarray to the formgroup. On console i am getting below error,

**ERROR
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.**

I have added formgroup but it is not showing as per expectation. I also created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-2-ht9sk7) for issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject FormBuilder as a dependency,

Instead of `private fb: FormBuilder;`

Add it to the constructor as follows:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

[Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-2-4ba6qf)

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder)

Comment: Thanks @Akshay. It worked for inputs but still showing error for table format.

Comment: Adding MatInputModule to module fixes that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to initialize FormGroup on ngOnInit:

```
this.UserForm = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
```

Firstname is only an example, there you need to define your fromControls, just like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {    
      this.getdata();

      this.UserForm = new FormGroup({
        page: new FormControl(),
        per_page: new FormControl(),
        total: new FormControl(),
        total_pages: new FormControl(),       
        UserArray: this.fb.array([])
        });    
  }
```