# ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. for datepicker using angular material 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am developing simple datepicker application. I have checked related post but couldnt solve this error. I am exactly following angular material exapmples.

Template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Material module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,

  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002237/7124761