# Error in browser Console mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 9 and Angular material 9.2.4
I am trying to use MatFormField.
Below is my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is my component.html

```
<p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
      <mat-label>Standard form field</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
      <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

But my form feild looks like

[image]

and I am having error in the console.
Kindly suggest what I am missing in the configuration

Comment: Can you rebuild your application and check?

Comment: Thanks It Worked.But what is the point of rebuilding? I hav also used material toolbar. The changes got reflected instantly. Why not for form field component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol)

Comment: @Greenbox sometime hot refresh will not  for some reason.

Comment: No. It might be because MatInput Module. But I was getting this error even after importing the MatInputModule also. After rebuilding the errors are no more

Answer (score 0):

Try importing **FormsModule** in your imports