# Material UI Datepicker not working on angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have integrated the material UI in my angular project using this command **ng add @angular/material** and I have imported the all necessary components on app.module.ts file but I am facing the below error
[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html code is fine. Make sure right imports have been made.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you forgot to import MatInputModule.

```
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: No, actually I have imported the both on app.module.ts