# Why is my mat-slide-toggle state changing, but the animations won't work unless I comment out my <ng-container> element?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Can someone explain to me why my material slider toggle animations break when I add my `<ng-container>` element?

I'm working on learning angular and material UI. I've got a little card created that does everything I want to, except that for some reason the `<mat-slide-toggle>` animations aren't working. The state of the toggle is reporting correctly, but the animations won't work unless I comment out everything in the `<ng-container>` element.

**Broken Example**

Toggled Off : [Toggle Off While ng-container is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvjNE.png)

Toggled On : [Toggle On While ng-container is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T93A2.png)

*Notice that the Enabled value changes, but the icon does not.*

**reverse-text.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card'
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reverse-text',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatCardModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './reverse-text.component.html',
  styleUrl: './reverse-text.component.css'
})
export class ReverseTextComponent {
  title = "Reverse Text"
  checked: boolean = false;
  textinput: string = "";
  reversedText = "";

  reverseText(unmixed: string) {
    var splitstring = unmixed.split("")
    var mixed = splitstring.reverse();
    var unmixed = mixed.join("");
    this.reversedText = unmixed;
  }
}
```

**reverse-text.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        Reverse Text
        <mat-slide-toggle class="example-margin" [checked]="checked" 
        (change)="checked = !checked">
                Enabled: {{checked}}
            </mat-slide-toggle>
    </mat-card-content>

    <ng-container *ngIf="checked">
        <mat-form-field>
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Enter text" #premixedtext></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <p class="output">
            {{reversedText}}
        </p>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="reverseText(premixedtext.value)">
            Reverse Text
        </button>
    </ng-container>
</mat-card>
```

Any help is appreciated. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the UI animations are broken!

**GitHub Repo : bwcii/playground**

I'm expecting that the mat-slide-toggle animations will visually represent if the ng-container is visually present or not. The toggle does correctly control if the ng-container element is present or not, but the UI elements is broken.

I've tried handling the event changes differently. I've done research on the documentation for mat-slide-toggle. I've confirmed that it works correctly when I remove the ng-container element, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? It's possible that it doesn't work due to runtime errors.

Comment: Let me check now. Can't believe I skipped this step.

Comment: Yep. This'll give me something to go off of. 

ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. Let's see how this shakes out.

Comment: Ugh. Yep. I was missing the import of "MatInputModule" which was causing the above error. Found the answer here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol 

Thanks for the help @JSONDerulo! Should have checked the console for errors first!

Answer (score 1):

Shout out to @JSONDerulo for reminding me of the basics.

This issue was fixed by importing "MatInputModule" to my standalone component.

Prior to doing this I was getting the following runtime error which was only visible in the browser console...

> ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Don't forget to check for runtime errors! Thank you all for your help!