# Abstracting a "God" Component Runtime Errors

Tags: angular

I have a client that essentially has a "God" component to spin up form fields. What makes this a bit hairy is that we're using material for non-mobile environments and ionic for mobile environments.

This component handles things like the type (text, textarea, select, etc.), the various inputs (placeholder, min, max, etc.), and wires up labels, prefixes, and suffixes so that all we have to do is create a new instance of this component and pass it the inputs necessary for the type, e.g.:

```html
<god-component type="textarea" placeholder="Something cool" controlName="SomethingCool"></god-component>
```

The issue with this approach is that if we need to make a change then we also need to regression test every type of input to make sure nothing broke.

I have been put in charge of refactoring it so that while the "God" component and all of its inputs still exist, it essentially abstracts the various control types into their own sub component. So what I've done is:

1. Create a form-field wrapper component that wire up the label, prefix, and suffix. This also uses `ng-container` to render the child component.
2. Create a mobile-form-field wrapper that does the same thing for mobile specific environments.
3. Create a textarea child component that uses a textarea with either `matInput` or `ion-textarea`
4. In my "God" component, replace the stuff for the textarea with the form-field/mobile-form-field wrapper and the textarea child component.

So for clarity, my form-field wrapper looks like this:

```html
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{ 'condensed': condensed }"
                [floatLabel]="condensed ? 'never' : 'auto'">
    <!-- Label -->
    <mat-label *ngIf="label">{{label}}</mat-label>

    <!-- Prefix -->
    <span *ngIf="prefix" matPrefix>{{prefix}}</span>

    <!-- Control -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>

    <!-- Suffix -->
    <span *ngIf="suffix" matSuffix>{{suffix}}</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

My textarea wrapper looks like this:

```html
<textarea *ngIf="!isMobile; else isMobileContainer"
          matInput
          inputs...></textarea>
  
<ng-template #isMobileContainer>
    <ion-textarea inputs...>
    </ion-textarea>
</ng-template>
```

And my "God" component changes:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="control && type && isProofOfConcept">
    <span>Proof of Concept</span>
    <!-- non mobile -->
    <form-field-wrapper *ngIf="!isMobile; else isMobileFormField"
                        inputs...>
        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="type">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="textAreaTemplate"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </form-field-wrapper>

    <!-- mobile -->
    <ng-template #isMobileFormField>
        <mobile-form-field-wrapper inputs...>
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="type">
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'" [ngTemplateOutlet]="textAreaTemplate"></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </mobile-form-field-wrapper>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- template -->
    <ng-template #textAreaTemplate>
        <textarea-child inputs></textarea-child>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

The issue with this is that when I go to run the code, I'm getting a runtime error:

> mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

So even though the textarea with `matinput` is a direct child of the mat-form-field when the DOM is rendered, I ***think*** because the form field wrapper uses ng-content and the "God" component an ngSwitch with an ngTemplateOutlet, that material library is complaining about that.

How can I refactor this so that I can abstract the child controls while also conforming to Material's rules without a ton of code reuse while keep the original definition of the "God" component?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide a playground

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705101/mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol)

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy - No it doesn't and I promise to you I did look at that thread before posting my question here. I even went so far as to take everything down to the barebones without the ngSwitch and ngTemplateOutlet to see if the problem still exists (and it does).

Comment: @David this thread has a link to https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411 where author struggled with the same problem. The issue was closed due to inactivity, there is no PR or other resolution. So it looks like `mat-form-field` doesn't support content projections. A few commenters suggested dirty workarounds with hidden fields or similar.

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy - I don't like it, but it works. By adding a hidden `matInput` to my form-field-wrapper component, the error goes away and the styling is applied. If you want to respond with an actual answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @David I think, by now you know about this problem a lot more than I do)) I think it would be best if you could describe the solution with all the links and explain why it didn't work as you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Volodymyr Usarskyy in the original post's comments, I was able to resolve the issue.

The relevant peice to all this is that `mat-form-field` doesn't really support content projection (e.g. `<ng-content>`) to project components that contain the `matInput`. This was made obvious by this github issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9411

To resolve my issue, I modified my form-field wrapper component to include a `matInput` that was hidden (and unused) which is definitely a code smell so I included a comment with it:

```html
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{ 'condensed': condensed }"
                [floatLabel]="condensed ? 'never' : 'auto'">
    <!--
        HACK: mat-form-field doesn't support projections
              this hidden matInput is a workaround to satisfy: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl
    -->
    <input matInput [hidden]="true">

    ... rest of code here

</mat-form-field>
```

So I'm going with a "hey, at least it works" attitude until this issue gets resolved by the Material team.